# Android Lubuntu - libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

I'm trying to set up an Android dev environment on Lubuntu but I keep getting this error when I load the emulator:

```
⇒ ./emulator-x86 -avd test
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
```

When I run it with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose I get:

```
⇒ ./emulator-x86 -avd test  
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL error: failed to open drm device: Permission denied
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/facetoe/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/facetoe/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/facetoe/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/facetoe/.drirc: No such file or directory.
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
```

The emulator runs very slowly and uses around 80% of my CPU. Has anyone encountered this or have any suggestions to make it work?

Edit: Ok I may have figured it out. Turns out I needed to add myself to the video group, logout and log back in. Additionally I had to run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/facetoe/programs/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/lib`. This seems to have fixed it, although I still get an error about audio...

Comment: The messages seem to indicate you are not allowed to load the library needed for hardware accelleration.

Answer (score 2):

`export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1` did it for me. It seems that the libstdc++ embedded with the emulator was too old compared to the rest of the system.

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android#libGL_error:_failed_to_load_driver:_swrast_OR_AVD_doesn.27t_load_and_no_error_message_displayed